# How does thermal expansion actually happen on the quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, electrons, orbital-motion

Classical physics states that when an object is heated, its particles gain kinetic energy, which causes them push away from each other. But on an even smaller level, what is actually happening?
I read it somewhere that when an object is heated, its electrons are bombarded by thermal photons. This apparently causes the electrons to gain energy and move to a higher energy state, and a longer orbit. Is this what happens or is there something else happening?

Comment: Do quantum effects come into play when heating something to temperatures high enough that cause it to expand?

Comment: Some materials shrink when heated --- that is, they have a negative coefficient of thermal expansion. A source which explains why that happens might start you along a path to a proper answer.

Comment: Or, more precisely, the coefficient of 'thermal expansion' is a function of temperature for all normal solids, and often can change from positive to negative here and there. The point to consider is not individual electrons, but the shape of the potential well that atoms sit in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the true reason behind thermal expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154821/whats-the-true-reason-behind-thermal-expansion)